# alert when user attempts to enter key into textbox

Tags: javascript, alert, textfield

So I've been searching for a bit now for code that will alert a user with a message (I know how to do an alert) when they try to enter any sort of text into a blank textbox.

Here is my code.  What do I add to cause the `sendMsg()` function to be called?

```
<script>
  function sendMsg()
  {
    alert ("change msg content here");
  }
</script>
```

here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="text" name="">
</body>
```

Comment: popups when you try typing? sounds annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" onKeyUp="sendMsg()" />
```

i.e. if I understood your question.

Cheers.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad :)    Do you reckon you could "tick the answer as correct"? (so that visitors later can see quickly what the situation is)

Comment: lol yeah im still waiting for the timer to go down so it will let me

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event.

```
<input type="text" name="" onchange="inputChanged();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving your input an ID:

```
<input id="testing" type="text" name="" />
```

And then your javascript would be:

```
document.getElementById('testing').onfocus = function() {
    // alert("change msg content here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll need to do is attach an event listener to the `focus` event of the text box (which is triggered when you "focus" on a text box), to do that you'll need some way of locating it in the DOM. The simplest way to do that would be to add an `id` attribute like so:

```
<body>
        <input type="text" name="" id="msgContent">
</body>
```

Now you can use the `document.getElementById` method to find the element:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('msgContent');
```

Then you can attach an event listener:

```
textBox.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    alert('change msg content here');
});
```

Keep in mind that the `addEventListener` method isn't available in some older versions of IE, instead there are other fallbacks [which are detailed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Finally if you're using a library like `jQuery`, `YUI`, etc you normalize the browser differences for attaching event handlers:

```
//jQuery example
$('#msgContent').on('focus', function () {
    alert('change msg content here');
});
```